# Autoplaying C# Mp3 Player

Tags: c#, mp3, autoplay

So my school blocked spotify and we have no way of listening to music so I made a Mp3 player. However after playing a file in the listbox I cannot get it to autoplay the next. I'm fairly new to C# so I might be slow with the uptake.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Mp3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string[] files, paths;

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
    }


    private void tableLayoutPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == 
System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
            paths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
            for(int i=0; i< files.Length; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: use a loop in the selectedIndexChanged  event and increment the index of your path array

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to search for a method that tells you when player is stopped, then you can select next index in list :

```
int listIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
listBox1.SelectedIndex = listIndex + 1;
```

Then pass this row to the player :

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
```